# How to create an external hive table from the header of a CSV file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a CSV file with header as below.

**Column1, Column2, ... Column150**

data1,data2,....        data150

I have around 150 columns and to create a hive table I need to give all the column names present in the header and need to skip header using skip.header.line.count=1

Here I am skipping the header and not using it for table creation.

> create external table EMPLOYEES
>   (
>
> column1 STRING,
>
> column2 STRING,....
>
> column150 STRING)
>
> LOCATION 'PATH'
>
> TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")

Is there anyway that I could create a table from the column names specified in the header with default datatype as STRING?

I know that I could copy the header and populate the create query.
But I just wanted to know whether I could specify a property in hive to load the column names from header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I often generate my create table statements with Python or R by reading the first line of my csv, building out the syntax, and sometimes even guessing at data types using the R package `readr`

Comment: Hive uses table definition to  interpret the content, what you are asking is to work the other way around, i don't think it is possible.

Comment: Hive doe not have such feature until now, easily use notepad++ and some regex to make the query.